# Change a set method in dalvik (smali code)

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, smali

I'm working on android reverse engineering that works online (json) by transferring data like wallet, price , id , code, ...

I have found a class that sets and gets Wallet value but can not figure out how to change it.

I'm noob in reversing. i think in the main activity this code gets wallet value from json and set it in the app.

```
Fragment_Main_Page.this.sharedPreference.setWallet(((Ser_FirstPage)paramAnonymousResponse.body()).getWallet());
```

this part , i think reads Wallet String from Server:

```
paramAnonymousResponse.body()).getWallet());
```

and then send it to sharedPreference class to set in program.

in sharedPreference class , setWallet method is :

```
public void setWallet(String paramString)
  {
    this.editor.putString("wallet", paramString);
    this.editor.commit();
  }
```

as you see ParamString must be the value i said before.

and set method smali code is :

```
method public setWallet(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .locals 2
    .param p1, "wallet"    # Ljava/lang/String;

    .prologue
    .line 247
    iget-object v0, p0, Lfenix/team/aln/mahan/component/ClsSharedPreference;->editor:Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;

    const-string v1, "wallet"

    invoke-interface {v0, v1, p1}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;->putString(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;

    .line 248
    iget-object v0, p0, Lfenix/team/aln/mahan/component/ClsSharedPreference;->editor:Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;

    invoke-interface {v0}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;->commit()Z

    .line 249
    return-void
.end method
```

I want to change "ParamString" in smali code to static String Value like "5000" or "Hello", not input Value that is received by setWallet(String paramString).

Like This:

```
public void setWallet(String paramString)
  {
    String str1="5000"
    this.editor.putString("wallet", str1);
    this.editor.commit();
  }
```

it is hard to change it in smali .

p.s: what is the best source/book for understanding smali instructions

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode is the primary reference for dalvik instructions.

Answer (score 1):

1. At first change number of locals: 
   `.locals 3`
2. Set value for new local: 
   `const-string v2, "5000"`
3. Replace local in method:

   ```
   invoke-interface {v0, v1, v2}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;->putString(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;
   ```

Final result:

```
method public setWallet(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .locals 3
    .param p1, "wallet"    # Ljava/lang/String;

    .prologue
    .line 247
    iget-object v0, p0, Lfenix/team/aln/mahan/component/ClsSharedPreference;->editor:Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;

    const-string v1, "wallet"

    const-string v2, "5000"

    invoke-interface {v0, v1, v2}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;->putString(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;

    .line 248
    iget-object v0, p0, Lfenix/team/aln/mahan/component/ClsSharedPreference;->editor:Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;

    invoke-interface {v0}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;->commit()Z

    .line 249
    return-void
.end method
```